# Splitting lines based on a delimiter in UNIX

Tags: string, unix, split

I have some data which is being returned by some SQL query which looks as below.I am trying to separate the lines based on a delimiter and send it to the new line.How can I do this in UNIX.. I tried using shell-scripting but couldn't make through...

```
ALB|1001|2012-04-15 ALB|1001|2012-04-14 ALB|1001|2012-04-16 ALB|1001|2012-04-17


ALB|1001|2012-04-15
ALB|1001|2012-04-14 
ALB|1001|2012-04-16 
ALB|1001|2012-04-17
```

Comment: Would you be open to a non-bash scripted solution? This would be fairly trivial in Python etc. e.g, `for i in s.split():print i` if `s` contains your string

Comment: Yes that space is coming as part of the output... I am trying to workout on UNIX..

Comment: better to fix your output line-seperator on the SQL tool that you are using. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you all for the help... :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For that particular example, `tr ' ' '\n' < file` ought to work:

```
echo "ALB|1001|2012-04-15 ALB|1001|2012-04-14 ALB|1001|2012-04-16 ALB|1001|2012-04-17" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: Loved it twalberg.. Its very simple and easy.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 9):

xargs is a simple single program you can use to do this, as in:

```
$ echo "ALB|1001|2012-04-15 ALB|1001|2012-04-14 ALB|1001|2012-04-16 ALB|1001|2012-04-17"|xargs -d' ' -n1
ALB|1001|2012-04-15
ALB|1001|2012-04-14
ALB|1001|2012-04-16
ALB|1001|2012-04-17
```

Comment: +1 been using `xarg`s for years, never looked at the command line options before, clearly a mistake.

Comment: `xargs` has a (hidden) drawback — it uses `/bin/echo` when no program to run has been specified and thus it's being run way too often — on every input element with noticeable performance penalties